# Find bounding box with C# using OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, bounding-box

I use the https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp wrapper to use opencv with C#.

Actually i would like to get the maximum bounding box of my countours. 
Tilt is irrelevant. I would like to get a perfect straight box.

My actual result after find contours looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  Mat src = new Mat("index.jpg", ImreadModes.GrayScale);
  // Mat src = Cv2.ImRead("lenna.png", ImreadModes.GrayScale);
  Mat dst = new Mat();
  Mat dst2 = new Mat();

  Cv2.Canny(src, dst, hScrollBar1.Value, hScrollBar2.Value);
  //using (new Window("src image", src)) ;
  //using (new Window("dst image", dst)) ;

  // Find contours
  OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours; //vector<vector<Point>> contours;
  HierarchyIndex[] hierarchyIndexes; //vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  Cv2.FindContours(dst, out contours, out hierarchyIndexes, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);
  using (new Window("dst image", dst)) ;
```

I saw that there is a function BoundingRect

```
 Cv2.BoundingRect()
```

Sound correct for me. But this function requires a InputArray named curve. 
Im a little bit confuesd.

Would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Thanks

Comment: normally you pass the contour you want to get the rectangle of. Just in case you need the rotated rectangle afterwards, minAreaRect will do the job and the input is the same, the contour (vector of points, at least in C++).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. BoundingBox requests curves from type OpenCvSharp.InputArray. My Contour is from type OpenCvSharp.Point[][]. So how should i convert the contours to the inputArray?

Comment: I haven't worked that much with the C# OpenCV, but in C++ inputArray is many things, like a Mat object or a vector of points, and it will convert it to what it needs implicitly. OpenCvSharp.Point[][] is a vector of vector of points, or a vector of contours, just pass one of them. FindContours, also receives inputArrays or inputOutputArrays

Comment: Unfortunatley it does not convert automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foud the solution by myself.

```
 var biggestContourRect = Cv2.BoundingRect(contours[0]);

        Cv2.Rectangle(dst,
            new OpenCvSharp.Point(biggestContourRect.X, biggestContourRect.Y),
            new OpenCvSharp.Point(biggestContourRect.X + biggestContourRect.Width, biggestContourRect.Y + biggestContourRect.Height),
            new Scalar(255, 255, 255),2);
```

Do the job :)

Comment: that was what i tried to tell you :) you passed one of the contours and it convert it automatically to inputarray. BTW, opencv rects has `tl()`and `br()` to give you the top left and bottom right points

Comment: Thank you. Im sorry that i didnt realized what you meant. By the way, i have an image which has multiple detected contour. Is there a way to get the bounding box of all detected contours?

Comment: sadly there is no direct method... just iterate through the vector :) in C++ there is an overload of rectangle which you can pass directly the rect instead of the points (rectangle(Mat& img, Rect rec, const Scalar& color)) which may make it easier to read :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like contours[0] is not the biggest contour at all. You need to loop through all the contours and compare each area with a temporary biggest contour.